# Saved PCA model produce different result

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I'm using PCA to reduce my feature vector dimension. I'm saving its model and transformed output like this:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib    
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca_transformed_fit = pca.fit(data)
pca_transformed = np.around(pca.fit_transform(data), 10)
np.savetxt('reducedFeatures.txt', pca_transformed, delimiter=',', newline='\n', fmt='%1.10f')
joblib.dump(pca_transformed_fit, 'pca.model')
```

`data` is the output of VGG16. As I want to have only 10 decimal places, I rounded the transformed output. So I want to use saved model to process feature vectors again with the code below:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

pca = joblib.load('pca.model')
pca_transformed = np.around(pca.transform(samples), 10)
np.savetxt('reducedFeatures_again.txt', pca_transformed, delimiter=',', newline='\n', fmt='%1.10f')
```

**BUT** the problem is the outputs are not the same for a given feature vector.

[image]

As long as these transformed data are very meaningful, what can I do to have the exact output?? 
If you need more clarification, just ask for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fitting the PCA twice in the first code snippet. First time here: `pca_transformed_fit = pca.fit(data)`, second time here: `pca_transformed = np.around(pca.fit_transform(data), 10)`. I guess there are some small computational errors that result in a slightly different decomposition upon every repeated call to `fit()` or `fit_transform()`. Replace `fit_transform()` with `transform()` and it should work (at least it worked for me when I tested it).

Comment: Sir, first of all THANK YOU! I don't know why I did this mess!!! It's obvious from docs that `fit_transform` produce different results than `fit` then `transform`. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: you're welcome!